# How to click a button inside a dialogue box in waitr

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I want to access different elements in a dialog box which opens after clicking on a button in page.For example i want to check  a radio button,entering  text ,clicking on  button and then close the dialog window.

Below is the html code:

```
div class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; height: 804.267px;"><iframe width="760px" height="800" frameborder="0" src="/apex/PreInstall_Notes?ContractID=800f00000006SVS&LangCode=USE&Order=False&AccountId=001f000000dea7Z">#document<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html><head> … </head><body><form id="j_id0:j_id31" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="https://c.cs16.visual.force.com/apex/PreInstall_Notes" method="post" name="j_id0:j_id31"><input type="hidden" value="j_id0:j_id31" name="j_id0:j_id31"></input><script> … </script><div class="apexp"><div class="individualPalette"><div class="accountBlock"><div id="j_id0:j_id31:thePageBlock" class="bPageBlock brandSecondaryBrd apexDefaultPageBlock secondaryPalette"><div class="pbHeader"> … </div><div class="pbBody"><span id="j_id0:j_id31:thePageBlock:j_id33"></span><div class="tableHead"> … </div><br></br><span id="j_id0:j_id31:thePageBlock:j_id60"><table class="tableCommon"><tbody><tr> … </tr><tr><td class="lblQuestions"> … </td><td> … </td></tr><tr> … </tr><tr> … </tr><tr> … </tr><tr> … </tr><tr> … </tr><tr> … </tr><tr> … </tr><tr> … </tr><tr id="groupDetailSection" style="display: none;"> … </tr><tr> … </tr><tr> … </tr><tr> … </tr><tr> … </tr><tr> … </tr><tr> … </tr><tr> … </tr><tr id="AEProvidedFloorPlan_ERB" style="display: none;"> … </tr><tr> … </tr></tbody></table></span></div><div class="pbBottomButtons"> … </div><div class="pbFooter secondaryPalette"> … </div></div></div></div></div><div id="j_id0:j_id31:j_id327"></div></form><span id="ajax-view-state-page-container" style="display: none"> … </span><script type="text/javascript"> … </script><div id="datePicker" class="datePicker"> … </div></body></html></iframe></div></div><div class="ui-widget-overlay" style="width: 1349px; height: 4172px; z-index: 1001;"></div></body></html>
```

Below is the html code for a button which i want to click inside that dialog window.Just want to know how to switch to the dialog window and perform on it.

```
td id="j_id0:j_id31:thePageBlock:j_id32" class="pbButton "><input id="j_id0:j_id31:thePageBlock:j_id32:btnSave" class="btn" type="submit" value="Save" name="j_id0:j_id31:thePageBlock:j_id32:btnSave"></input><input id="j_id0:j_id31:thePageBlock:j_id32:btnCancel" class="btn" type="submit" onclick="closePopupWindow();" value="Cancel" name="j_id0:j_id31:thePageBlock:j_id32:btnCancel"></input
```

Comment: The question is a hard to follow - (1) The first block of HTML code is hard to read since it is not in a code block and indented. (2) The relation between the first and second piece of HTML is not obvious - ie the first block of code does not contain the button. (3) It is unclear if by "dialog window" you mean an actual window or just a perceived popup on the page. Clarifying these might help you get a better answer. However, my guess is that the problem is with the button being in an iframe, which you need to explicitly tell Watir.

Comment: Hi @JustinKo :It is popup window.This open up by clicking on a button in a page.Once this window open up you cannot access any element in the parent page. when i inspect element of that popup window it starts with above HTML code. and inside the popup window  there are many radio buttons ,text fields which i need to click and enter.When i inspect the save button inside the popup window it gave me the above Html code. My question how to access the elements of the popup window.Thanks for your help.

Comment: Given that you have a div with class "ui-dialog-content", are you sure it is not a modal dialog on the actual page? For example, is it like the jQuery one (http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) where you cannot move the popup outside of the browser or an actual modal dialog (https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/domref/showModalDialog.html) where you can drag the dialog outside of the browser?

Comment: No @JustinKo: I cannot move the the pop dialog.When it open up you cannot do anything in the parent page.for that  you need to close this popup 1st.somy test case is i click on a button which open this popup.Need to perform some thing in this popup window and click on save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the HTML, I would guess that the "dialog window" is actually just a div tag within the main browser. The div also includes an iframe, which needs to be explicitly stated when using elements within it.

Try:

```
browser.iframe(:src => /PreInstall_Notes/).button(:id => /btnSave/).click
```